# Can a constructor for a super class return instances of a sub class instead?

Tags: python, oop

I am parsing a binary log file.  The log file is formatted as follows: every 10 bytes is a record, the first byte of the record is the record type, the next 5 bytes are a timestamp and the last 4 bytes are record type specific data.

Currently I am doing the following:

```
# read the input binary stream
with open(filename, mode='rb') as trace_stream:
    # create an empty list of trace records
    trace = []
    # iterate over each record in the binary stream
    for record_type, record_data in yield_record(trace_stream,
                                                 size=RECORD_LENGTH):
        # create a new record instance
        if record_type == SEN_RECORD:
            new_record = sen_record(record_data)
        elif record_type == DSP_RECORD:
            new_record = dsp_record(record_data)
        elif record_type == USO_RECORD:
            new_record = uso_record(record_data)
        elif record_type == SDM_RECORD:
            new_record = sdm_record(record_data)
        elif record_type == DOC_RECORD:
            new_record = doc_record(record_data)
        elif record_type == DAT_RECORD:
            new_record = dat_record(record_data)
        elif record_type == LAT_RECORD:
            new_record = lat_record(record_data)
        elif record_type == SWI_RECORD:
            new_record = swi_record(record_data)
        elif record_type == FTL_RECORD:
            new_record = ftl_record(record_data)

        # append this new record to our trace
        trace.append(new_record)
```

Where sen_record, dsp_record, uso_record etc. are all sub-classes of a generic record class

What I would like to do is the following:

```
# read the input binary stream
with open(filename, mode='rb') as trace_stream:
    # create an empty list of trace records
    trace = []
    # iterate over each record in the binary stream
    for record_type, record_data in yield_record(trace_stream,
                                                 size=RECORD_LENGTH):
            new_record = record(record_data)

    trace.append(new_record)
```

And then have the record class constructor do the work of determining what type of record it is and creating the appropriate class instances.  Ideally my "main" routine shouldn't need to know about the record types?

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You might be able to override the `record`'s [`__new__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__) method to return an instance of a subclass.

Comment: Have you come across Python's [`struct`](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html) module to handle unpacking binary data, by the way?

Comment: @katrielalex I am using the struct module inside the constructors of each record sub class, since each record type interprets its data differently.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It would be simpler just to store the mapping

```
record_types = {SEN_RECORD: sen_record,
                DSP_RECORD: dsp_record,
                USO_RECORD: uso_record,
                SDM_RECORD: sdm_record,
                DOC_RECORD: doc_record,
                DAT_RECORD: dat_record,
                LAT_RECORD: lat_record,
                SWI_RECORD: swi_record,
                FTL_RECORD: ftl_record}
```

somewhere, and use that to look up the correct record type. (Note that you can do this, because classes are just objects, so you can put them in a dictionary.)

Specifically, you'd do

```
new_record = record_types[record_type](record_data)
```

---

There are more complicated ways of doing this (say if you wanted the subclasses to be created dynamically and automatically registered with their superclass upon creation), but there's no need to employ them in your situation.

Comment: I like this.  Not perfect but much cleaner than what I had.

Comment: "Not perfect"??!! The alternative is to implement `__new__` in some base class, and then contaminate the base class with knowledge of its subclasses so it know which type to instantiate. In Python terms, I don't know of a righter answer.

Comment: Since you say your constants `SEN_RECORD` etc. are integers 0 to 10, the `record_types` can be a simple array instead of a dictionary, with no other code change.  Of course, that means you may have to change `record_types` if you change the constants.

Answer (score 3):

There is a way to do this but I don't recommend you use it.  I recommend simply using a factory function to construct and return the correct type of object based on the record.

```
def create_record(record_type):
  if record_type == SEN_RECORD:
    return sen_record(record_data)
  ...
```

To override the behavior of object creation, you can provide a `__new__` method in the class.  See the [official docs](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__) for details.  But again, I do not recommend this; for all but the most specialized applications, using this is playing with fire.

Answer (score 2):

Since it's nice to learn about the dynamic features of Python, here's how you can do this 'magically'. It's not a great idea to do this sort of thing in real code though -- it's fragile and can lead to unexpected behaviour. It's also [putting data in your variable names](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201112/keep_data_out_of_your_variable_names.html), which is a bad habit.

Also, you can't quite do what you want, because there's an issue with the sequence of operations. Specifically, when you define `Record` you can't have defined its subclasses yet (obviously). So you can't at that point put the dispatching logic into the class. But there's no other distinguished time at which you can say "now we've finished defining subclasses, set up the dispatch", so you have to hard-code it into your source code after all the subclass definitions. Then you might as well hard-code the dict as in my other answer.

Anyway, with that disclaimer, here's the magic. (It only works for new-style classes.)

```
@classmethod
def update_record_types(cls):
    cls.records = {c.__name__.upper(): c for c in cls.__subclasses__()}
```

Then `Record.__init__` just refers to the class attribute `records`, which you can update at any time by calling `Record.update_record_types()`.

---

EDIT: I guess I should point out how to use this!

```
>>> class Record(object):
...     @classmethod
...     def update_record_types(cls):
...         cls.records = {c.__name__.upper(): c for c in cls.__subclasses__()}
... 
>>> # define some record types, each with their own __init__
>>> class sen_record(Record): pass
>>> class dsp_record(Record): pass
>>> class uso_record(Record): pass
>>>
>>> # update the listing of record types
>>> Record.update_record_types()
>>>
>>> # look up the one you want
>>> Record.records["SEN_RECORD"]
<class '__main__.sen_record'>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do it using `eval`.  I have to make an assumption about your data though, that your `record_type` field is one of the values "SEN", "DSP", etc.  I'm also going to assume that your parser does **validation** of the data, otherwise this code would be a huge security hole.  (As it is, there is a performance penalty for doing this (versus a dictionary or factory function), but it is sort of "magical" as you desire.)

```
class SEN_record(record):
  ...

class DSP_record(record):
  ...

... # other record subclasses similarly defined here

# read the input binary stream
with open(filename, mode='rb') as trace_stream:
    # create an empty list of trace records
    trace = []
    # iterate over each record in the binary stream
    for record_type, record_data in yield_record(trace_stream,
                                                 size=RECORD_LENGTH):
        trace.append(eval("%s_record(record_data)" % (record_type,)))
```

Comment: (Slightly) less of a gaping security hole would be to look up the class in `globals()`.

Comment: Slick, however record_type is an integer between 0 and 10.  So I would still have to have a look up to get the appropriate string.  Nevertheless cool.